# How to initialize new object each time for resetting game in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to recreate new object each time user press <kbd>c</kbd> key so that I can load game once again from start point. But I'm not able to find a way to do so.

This is what I've tried so far:

```py
def initializeGame(theGame):

    while run:
        theGame.clock.tick(FPS)

        # This function consists code for Events
        theGame.events()
        # This function consists code from enemy hit events
        theGame.hit_or_not()
        # This function consists code for bullet hit events
        theGame.bulletHit_or_not()
        # This function consists code for player movements
        theGame.movements()
        # This function consists code for drawing the sprites over the screen
        theGame.redrawGameWindow()

def startGame(run):
    first_game = Game()

    while run:
        initializeGame(first_game)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False

        if keys[pygame.K_c]:
            new_game = Game()
            initializeGame(new_game)

startGame(True)
```

All I want to do is when I press 'c' key the game must restart from starting point and for that I have to recreate new 'Game()' class object and initialize the game

Game Class Code - https://pastebin.com/abAiey34

Comment: Could you fix the indentation? indentation is important in python, your code would raise several `syntax error` due to wrong indentation

Comment: indentation is already ok

Comment: Yeah, Rabbid76 edited your post to fix it while I was commenting, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid a game loop in the game loop, this means remove the loop from `initializeGame`.
The name `initializeGame` is misleading, call it `runGame`:

```py
def runGame(theGame):

    # This function consists code for Events
    theGame.events()
    # This function consists code from enemy hit events
    theGame.hit_or_not()
    # This function consists code for bullet hit events
    theGame.bulletHit_or_not()
    # This function consists code for player movements
    theGame.movements()
    # This function consists code for drawing the sprites over the screen
    theGame.redrawGameWindow()
```

So it is sufficient to have a single `game`, which is just "reset" ba creating an ew game object.
In the one and only game loop `runGame` has to be called:

```py
def startGame(run):

    game = Game()
    while run:
        theGame.clock.tick(FPS)

        # run the game
        runGame(game)

        # get keys
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # handle keys
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False
        if keys[pygame.K_c]:
            game = Game()

startGame(True)
```

Note, `startGame()` already has a loop, so there is no necessity for a further game loop in any function. `runGame()` does all the things which have be done in on frame of the game. `runGame()` is continuously called in the game loop in `startGame()`.
If a new game has to be started, it is sufficient to create a  new `Game` object.

---

Note, the states which are returned by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) are evaluated, when the [`pygame.event`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) are handled by either [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) or [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).
Call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` after the event loop.

I would prefere a slightly different designe. Get the events in the main loop (`pygame.event.get()`) and pass them to `runGame()` and further to `Game.events()`:

```py
class Game:

    # [...]

    def events(self, eventlist):

        for event in eventlist:
            # handle events
            # [...]

def runGame(theGame, eventlist):

    # This function consists code for Events
    theGame.events(eventlist)

    # [...]

def startGame(run):

    game = Game()
    while run:
        theGame.clock.tick(FPS)

        # run the game
        eventlist = pygame.event.get()
        runGame(game, eventlist)

        # get keys
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # handle keys
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False
        if keys[pygame.K_c]:
            game = Game()
```

Comment: Bro i Didnt get it can you please explain in more detail - sorry for being a noob

Comment: @hotstepper One game loop is sufficient, the game loop is in `startGame`. In this loop `runGame` is called continuously. To start a new game all you've to do is to create a new `Game` object and assign it to `game`. The old game is destroyed and a new game is constructed.

Comment: @hotstepper `theGame` was a typo in the answer, it has to be `game`. It is corrected now.

Comment: I tried your code but when I press 'c' key nothing happens

Comment: @hotstepper Did you verify that `game = Game()` is executed when "c" is pressed?. Are all game states object attributes of the class `Game`? I can't see the class `Game`, so I can't know what's wrong.

Comment: Please kindly check my code - I have added a link at the bottom in my question kindly check it

Comment: Man don't leave me - I'm stuck at this point from last 2 days - Please Help me

Comment: @hotstepper In the linked code. there is still a loop in `newGame`, remove it (remove `while run:`)!